# A statement to modify a column to utf8 gives error when using (ALTER IGNORE TABLE with MODIFY )

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am updating a column to UTF-8 because I need to input Korean characters.

Originally, I ran the below query without IGNORE, but it through an error.

```
ALTER TABLE db_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'PRDP' at row 199593

I searched and found this:

[MySQL Documentation 5.7 says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> Strict mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date: If strict mode is not enabled, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce no warning. If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

When I ran it with IGNORE it gave me this:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE db_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE TABLE db_name MODIFY column_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4' at line 1

I checked the statement on a sql syntax validator (eversql) and it did not catch that error.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ALTER IGNORE TABLE` syntax. See documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

EverSQL is apparently validating syntax that doesn't exist in MySQL.

The SQL mode documentation you linked to is referencing the `INSERT IGNORE` statement.

To resolve your error you have two choices:

- Before you run ALTER TABLE, replace all date values like '0000-00-00' with a valid date, or else NULL.
- Disable the strict option in the `sql_mode` at least in the session where you run your ALTER TABLE.